# Does MD5 encode data or just 32 Bit string out of it?

Tags: c#, java, security, encoding, cryptography

I was wondering: does MD5 encode data? Because when it encodes the hash it's just 32 bits even if you encode data that of petabytes.

Does MD5 encode the data or just pull the hash key out of it to just compare?

Or did I just misunderstand the term "encoding"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MD5 is a **hashing** algorithm.

Whatever you feed it, you get 128 bits out.

It doesn't do any sort of encoding.

Encoding is the process of converting something from one representation to another - it can be lossy or non-lossy (that is, information can be lost in the encoding process, but depending on the process, it might preserve all data). Examples of encodings are ASCII and UTF-8, which are conventions of how to represent text in a computer.

Comment: Ok And One One Thing, Did MD5 Encrypts Data?

Comment: @ArsalHussain - No. Encryption is a two way process. Hashing isn't.

Comment: If the set of possible inputs is limited, it may be possible to guess at the original text.

Comment: Another relevant example of an encoding would be the hex encoding, which is typically used to represent the output of a hash function in a human-readable format.